# Rails: Capybara, checkboxes and Ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm building a list of user to send emails to, which is coded as (haml, though that's not the point)

```
  - @users.each do  |user|
    .field<
      = check_box_tag "user_ids[#{user.id}]",user.id
      %nbsp
      = user.name
```

The code works fine (though it can be probably refactored). However, I have problem writing Capybara tests because object ids change over time. For instance, I have the following cucumber test:

```
.....
Given user "User one" exists
And "User two" esists
......
When I check "user_ids_152"
And I check "user_ids_153"
.....
```

I get 
Capybara::ElementNotFound: cannot check field, no checkbox with id, name, or label 'user_ids_152' found

since user id is now 272. I searched and couldn't find a suitable solution here on SO.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your requirements, but adding an HTML label for your checkbox would make it easier to consistently check via Capybara:

```
%label{ :for => "user_ids_#{user.id}"}
  = check_box_tag "user_ids[#{user.id}]",user.id, :id => "user_ids_#{user.id}"
  = user.name
```

Then you could do:

```
When I check "User one"
```

I should add that the more you write well-formed, standards-compliant HTML, the easier it will be for you to use something like Capybara in the long run. The rails view helpers do a good job of helping you along if you use them, but just take note of any HTML you are generating outside of them.

I like Bullet Proof Web Design as a primer for that:

http://www.simplebits.com/publications/bulletproof/

Comment: Yes, it works fine! I had to correct the (bootstrap) form style to "form-horizontal", otherwise I'd have the checkbox on one line and the label on the other.